# Changing column value when another column is None

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I'm trying to set the value of column A to column B when column C is None

Here's what I'm using now:

```
df_final.loc[df_final['V3'].notnull(), 'Product Description'] = df_final['Original Description']
```

Thank you in advance for your help!

Comment: What's A/B/C here? Shouldn't you use `isnull()`? `df.loc[df['C'].isnull(), 'A'] = df['B']`